# Hibernate mapping - The content of element type "class" must match "(meta*,subselect

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I've a problem with the mapping of a class on hibernate...
I've already checked on the web, but i don't find the same problem

This is the error:

```
The content of element type "class" must match "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,tuplizer*,(id|
 composite-id),discriminator?,natural-id?,(version|timestamp)?,(property|many-to-one|one-to-one|component|dynamic-
 component|properties|any|map|set|list|bag|idbag|array|primitive-array)*,((join*,subclass*)|joined-subclass*|union-
 subclass*),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,filter*,fetch-profile*,resultset*,(query|sql-query)*)".
```

and this is my code:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

    <hibernate-mapping>
       <class name="it.****.extractor.application.DGEPRA" table="T_DGEPRA_LOG">

          <id name="id" type="int" column="ID"/>  

          <property name="time" column="TIME" type="timestamp"/> 
          <property name="function" column="FUNCTION" type="string"/>
          <property name="executionTime" column="EXECUTION_TIME" type="int"/>
          <property name="guId" column="GUID" type="string"/>

       </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

any idea?

Comment: Why do you use stars here `name="it.****.extractor.application.DGEPRA"`?

Comment: simply because my customer don't want his name on the web..

Comment: I found that it work fine if I add this:
      <id name="id" type="int" column="ID">
      <generator class="assigned"/>
      </id>  
But on my table I don't have any id... I must add it?

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: Any chance you reordered the child elements of your `class` tag?
They must go precisely in the order specified by the DTD (`id` before `property` etc)

Comment: no, any change... it work only if I define an id... but in this table i don't have any id..

Comment: @Lele I am confused. You say you don't have any id in the table, but in your mapping, you specified that property `id` in your java class corresponds to `ID` column in the DB. The DTD clearly states that a `class` tag must have either `id` or `composite-id` child. The syntax of document you posted looks correct, but try using some DTD-aware validator on your file to check schema conformance (to check if it results in the same error you receive)